# Как получить содержимое блока по клику?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте

Есть примерно такая разметка:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста, как с помощью JS получить содержимое каждого блока при клике по нему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учите основы, пригодится.
[События](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events).
[Делегирование](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation).
[Свойства нод](https://learn.javascript.ru/basic-dom-node-properties).

```js
document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('click', e => {
  // e.target - целевой элемент
  let content = e.target.innerHTML;
  
  console.info(`Содержимое элемента: "${content}"!`);
});
```

```css
div{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще так:

```js
div = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper div');
output = document.querySelector('output');
  
  div.forEach(get);
  
  function get(e){
   e.addEventListener('click', function(){
     output.innerHTML = 'Содержимое: ' + e.innerHTML;
    })
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
<output></output>
```

Comment: Никогда не видел тега `output`, что за тег такой?