# Получить содержимое Заголовок из блока по клику Есть три карточки, как при нажатие на первую карточку получать название этой карточки

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="container">
// Карточка 1
<div class="card">
               
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Заголовок 1</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Текст 1</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Изменить</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Сохранить</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</button>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>

// Карточка 2
<div class="card">
               
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Заголовок 2</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Текст 2</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Изменить</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Сохранить</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</button>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>
// Карточка 3
<div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Заголовок 3</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Текст 3</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Изменить</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Сохранить</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</button>
                </div>`введите сюда код`
                <hr>
            </div>
</div
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить содержимое блока по клику?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617849/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При условии, что у всех карточек есть заголовок, в противном случае нужно делать условие на существование заголовка

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const cardTitles = document.querySelectorAll(".card-title");

cards.forEach((card, index) => {
  card.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(cardTitles[index].innerText);
  });
});
```

Comment: Может `innerText` в `textContent`?